# Chat application for android and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, chat

I am developing an android application and I need to embed chat in that application.
The server side  is written in ASP.net ,C#.
Any suggestion to implement real time chat, push notification **without using GCM** or any third party application because we have some security concern.

Any suggestion would be appericiated
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

To implemented chat in Asp.net, you can use **SignalIR**

A simple to guide to implemented SignalIR, you can find [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/78d182/signalr-sample-chat-application-in-C-Sharp/)

Answer (score 0):

and you can use the following libraries

1. [SocketIO](http://socket.io/)
2. [WebSocket](https://www.websocket.org/)